# Excel 2010 on multi monitor screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-excel-2010

With office 2010 I would like to open two excel document on different monitor.
The only way I achieved to do this was to widden the Excel main window over the both screen which is not very convenient because:

- the mouse operation is not so easy.
- it hides what is between the two excel sheet.

Excel 2007 used to perform this very easily with a multi window system. Is there a tricks for 2010?

Comment: I'm on windows 7

Comment: Running Windows 7 myself and Excel 2010, and when I open two different Excel files, they open in separate windows, which means I can put one on each screen. What is your selection on File > Options > Advanced > Display > "Show all windows in the taskbar"?

Comment: Excel 2007 has a multi-window system? Where was that found? I have a custom add-in that adds the option to spread the Excel app window across multiple monitors (among other functions). That might be something worth looking at. I would avoid opening multiple instances of Excel, as this limits the work you can do between two books.

Comment: @JBirch - got that checked, and got two buttons on the taskbar, but the windows are not separable. It's just one window, with two "fake" buttons on the taskbar. Can you show a screenshot?

Answer (score 14):

You can run multiple instances of Excel by selecting Excel in Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Office -> Microsoft Excel 2010.  Or better yet pin this to the start menu or quicklaunch/taskbar.  You then have multiple instances.

If you then have the issue of opening Excel by double-clicking on an Excel ***file***, then you can do the things related in this post [Open Excel Files In New Window](https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window/197503#197503).  I'm on Win7x64 and had to install [Excel Launchpad](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/Excel-Instance-Launcher.shtml).  Worked like a champ!

[EDIT 12/2012: the utility is now called "Excel Launchpad", link updated]

[EDIT 7/2017: updated link]

Answer (score 7):

Another trick in Windows 7 is to Shift-Click the Excel item in the task bar to open a new instance.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion - very quick/easy.  Also works for other applications.

Answer (score 2):

> Got this from an outside source and thought I would share :)  In
>   Windows 7 you have to edit the registry to remove DDE completely. This
>   should work for Vista too. Check the "Ignore other applications that
>   use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)" box in Excel -> Excel Options ->
>   Advanced This alone might work for you by itself - didn't for me, I
>   got an error every time I double-clicked on an excel document. BACK UP
>   your registry.
>
> Open regedit, browse to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.8\shell\Open
>   Delete the ddeexec key, (or just rename it if you are worried - i just
>   renamed it and it worked) Then click on the "command" key and replace
>   the /e on the Default and command string in that key with "%1" Quotes
>   around %1 are important. NO QUOTES MEANS NO WORKIE!!!!
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.8\shell\Open\command should look like
>   this: (Default) REG_SZ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" "%1 command REG_MULTI_SZ
>   vUpAVX!!!!!!!!!MKKSkEXCELFiles>tW{~$4Q]c@II=l2xaTO5 "%1"
>
> Do the same for Excel.Sheet.12 Now Both .xls and .xlsx should open in
>   new windows with no errors.
>
> I have confirmed that the same problem occurs in Office 2010x64 (32bit
>   probably also) when checking the dde option. This should fix All vista
>   and windows 7 problems with opening excel in seperate windows :)
>   Enjoy!

From: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c42f825d-b7e8-48c8-b5af-30563b839f09/windows-7-cannot-run-multiple-instances-of-excel-using-ignore-other-applications-that-use-dde

Works for me!

Comment: Can confirm this is what I did awhile ago and it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

simply open new tab on the window and just go to open file....browse .... and open the file...it will duplicate windows.

Enjoy...

Comment: How, exactly, do you "simply open new tab on the window" in Excel?