# How to: edit data in excel, visualize it on a second screen whilst live?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, visualization

Suppose I have the following set-up:

I have a laptop connected to a screen. The screen shows whatever. The screen is in front on an audience who are asked to choose between several alternatives, say A, B and C.

Someone counts the votes and someone else enters them into an excel in the following columns:

A ----  number of votes
B ----  number of votes
C ----  number of votes

BUT: when the audience looks at the screen, they see only the bar chart (or pie chart, or whatever chart) that is made from this data. So, with every new vote count entered into that table, the chart changes.

So basically the question is: can I show a graph on a screen whilst I'm still entering the data that the graph is based on into excel, without the audience ever noticing the excelsheet?

EDIT: 
I'm afraid I haven't made myself entirely clear when asking the question. What I meant by 'showing to the audience' is that they see the graph and only the graph. So basically, they would see it the way they would see it if the graph was copy-pasted as a live connection into a powerpoint. The only see a fully blank screen with the graph on it, nothing more.

This means I'm not looking for a method to create double windows and position one window onto the second screen.

The perfect solution would be to find a way to copy-paste the graph to a powerpoint slide, have the powerpointslide up and actively presenting on screen two, whilst editing the excel on screen one.

Comment: You are not logged in, so your recent edit was made by an anonymous user and is pending approval at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by linking your visualization workbook to data in a separate workbook opened in the same instance of Excel. Using the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/273977/need-two-excel-windows-side-by-side-on-different-monitors-in-the-same-instance), have your data entry workbook on your laptop screen and the visualization workbook on the presentation screen. This will keep your data entry hidden from audience view.