# How to display 2 excel sheets in 2 interconnected monitors by default without needing to manually move them?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, multiple-monitors

I have 2 Excel sheets and 2 monitors that are interconnected. I want Book1 to display in one screen and Book2 to display on another instantly the moment I turn it on. However, when I turn them on, both files open in the same Excel instance, and when I use the "Shift + click new Excel in taskbar and open Book2" trick, both display at the same screen.

Now I have 2 questions.

1. How to open both books in separate instances the moment I double click their links?
2. How to make the Excel documents to default so that Book1 displays at monitor 1 and Book2 display at monitor 2 when they open? Without the need to drag them.

Comment: [Need two excel windows side by side, on different monitors, in the same instance](https://superuser.com/q/273977/241386)

Comment: I can get them to display separately now. But there's another issue. How can I tell one sheet to display at the left screen and tell another to display at the right screen? I don't want to have to drag them separately every time I turn them on.

Comment: That is a new question @hjh93, so I suggest you re-ask :)