# How do I get .XLT files to open in a new instance of excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, file-association

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Excel files in new window](https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window)

If I have a copy of excel open, and I double click a .xlt template file, it opens in the same excel instance that I have open (proven by viewing the processes in task manager, only one instance of excel is running).

I would like these to open in a new instance of excel (as this behavior causes conflict with a third party excel management tool I use), how do I edit Window's file association for this type, so that this happens?