# Open Excel worksheets in separate windows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Excel files in new window](https://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window)

I would like to open each of the worksheets of a single Excel file in a separate window, so that I can have one open on each monitor. In addition, I need to be able to edit in both windows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open separate worksheet TABS at the same time and then arrange them INSIDE the Excel window.

1. Open your file
2. Go to the View menu at the top.
3. Click on New Window.
4. Resize the Excel window to fit across both screens.
5. On the View menu, choose Arrange All -> Vertical to put them side-by-side.
   (You can do this manually by resizing the panes within Excel's window.

Is this better?

Comment: Doing this only allows me to edit in one window. I've updated the question, sorry for not providing this detail.

Comment: @Matt This lets me open multiple instances of Excel 2010 and edit in all the windows. Are you loading a file downloaded from the internet or containing macros, and if you are, did you click enable on the security warnings?

Comment: You can always [edit] your existing post – there's no need to add another answer to the question. Please remember that for the future, and welcome to Super User :) Pinging @Matt about the update.

Comment: Accepting because it is the closest approximation I think exists. Unfortunately, does not work elegantly for monitors with different resolutions (which also covers the combination of portrait/landscape), but I've been unable to find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. right click on a sheet
2. select **move or copy** from the menu
3. choose **move**
4. **from book** option select **new book**
5. Click **OK**

That should do the trick.  Then repeat the steps to put it back together.