# Open Excel files from Hyperlink in new window

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, hyperlink

Much like [this question](https://superuser.com/q/21602/107930) but I want to be able to insert a Hyperlink into one sheet that opens another sheet in a new window.

P.S. Using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

First you must do what is said in the question I linked to to make normal sheets open in separate windows. Then you can use:

```
=HYPERLINK("excel /e '\\Path\File.xlsx'","Open the file")
```