# Outlook attachment opening issue when Excel configured to open in new window?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-registry, microsoft-office-2010, attachments

I was tired of Excel opening additional documents within the same instance, so I looked into how to force it to open a new instance for each file. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/21604/57995) worked great.

However, I then got an error every time I tried to open a file from Explorer instead of going to Open from within Excel. [This post](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2012/06/05/Microsoft-Excel-on-Multi-Monitor-Machines.aspx) helped me correct that by editing some Excel registry entries. I did the same for CSV as was listed for the Sheet.# entries in that blog post.

Now I'm just left with one lingering issue - I can't open an Excel attachment directly from Outlook. It opens Excel, but no document is open and no error message is displayed. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Does preview inside of Outlook work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue resolved itself after a reboot.