# Excel: Do not open files in multiple instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-explorer

How do I open all excel files in the same instance/window by default (happens only when I open from the menu, but not from the windows explorer)?

I have this option unchecked, but is still not working: "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)."

Thank you :)

Comment: By default this is what happens. You need to create another instance of the application to open separately. Do you have a screenshot? I don't know of a reason for it to act differently, at least not in excel.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right Excel version number? I believe they changed the default behavior in 2013 - from 2010 and earlier, everything opened in one window by default.

Comment: For the exact opposite problem, see http://superuser.com/questions/21602/open-excel-files-in-new-window

Answer (score 2):

This functionality does not exist in Excel 2013.

In Excel 2010:

Try the following steps: File > Options > Advanced then under the Display heading, uncheck "Show all windows in the Taskbar" and click OK.

I had to close all open workbooks and make the change before it started working for files opened from both the menu and Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Found my own answer based on forum mrexcel.

Using program FilesTypeMan; On line excel.exe: Remove "%1" from the end of the Command Line and add [open("%1")] in the DDE message.

Answer (score 0):

My Excel 2010 crashed and I suddenly started having the same problem. Here's what worked for me:
Right click any .xls file in windows explorer.
Hover over "Open With" then click "Choose Default Program".
Choose any program that isn't excel.
Then repeat and choose excel.